# Doom: The Boardgame Scenario Guide for download?

Tags: doom

Does anyone know if the Scenario Guide for *Doom: The Boardgame* is available somewhere for download in English? Unfortunately it is not on the [Fantasy Flight archive page](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_nrep.asp?eidm=19).

I've got the game in German, but want to play it with an English speaker, and with the original Scenario Guide it would be much easier than translating myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a download site for this.  However, Fantasy Flight are *extremely* good about sending replacement components, so it may be worth just emailing their customer service and asking for one.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, since I'm not a FF customer having only the German edition, but I followed your suggestion and they actually are sending me a copy (internationally no less). Thank you for the suggestion.